# Android Wear 2.0 activity stack & notifications

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification, android-wear-2.0

Currently working a music player app for Androdi Wear 2.0, which has the followings activities:

- Library
- Playlists
- Playlist
- NowPlaying

The user opens the app and sees **Library** and then navigates to **Playlists** picks a specific **Playlist** and taps shuffle to start playing music and open the **NowPlaying** activity.

The user now gets a notification which link which starts the **NowPlaying** activity when tapped, Great!

But when I swipe to the right to navigate back to my notifications I'm not going back to the notifications but to **Playlist**...

How do I make the activity opened by my notification seperate from the existing stack and don't add it either to the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add into pendingintent this:

`intent.addFlag( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`

and/or add manifest file
`android:noHistory="true"` to your activity.